# PC won't boot - Reasons unknown

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

So a few weeks back I bought a GTX 980 and in order to power it with longevity in mind, a Corsair AX860, an 860W Platinum PSU.

It was working for two weeks and then I got "power surge warning/error" as my computer shut off from time to time. I figured it was either the board or the PSU.
So I waited for my next paycheck, bought the mainboard I wanted to upgrade to anyway and tested it out two days ago. Nothing.
The fans start spinning momentarily and then instantly stop again.

I figured: If it's not the mainboard, it has to be the PSU.

So today I plugged in my "old" (1,5 years old to be exact) 500W BeQuiet Bronze PSU. Weirdly enough the issue kept persisting.

So now I'm here, not knowing why my computer won't boot, even though both PSU and MB seem to be just fine.

I have tested with 4, 2 and lastly just **1 RAM stick** in and with only 2 SSDs connected for boot + data drive.

**My Specs:**

- Case: Corsair 750D
- CPU: Intel i7 4790k
- Cooler: EKWB Supremacy EVO (+ Reservoir + Pump + 240-Rad)
- PSU: Corsair AX860
- Mainboard: Asus Z97-WS (or Z87-Pro)
- RAM: Kingston Fury 2400MHz 32GB
- GPU: Asus Strix GTX 980 (or Asus 750Ti)
- 2 Samsung SSDs

I don't think it's just the pump that won't start, otherwise the PC would still have to boot up at least for a few seconds (aside from passive cooling even without the pump on)

So my only remaining question could be: **Did my CPU die?** I don't have a spare to test it with.

One more thing: The POST Code only shows 00 for a second before powering off.

**Edit01:** I've added a video showing the issue
[VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qnAW9zCJYLNG1DUzN2NTBvZUU/view?usp=sharing)

**Edit02:** Thanks to [Andrew Morton](https://superuser.com/users/272824/andrew-morton) I've booted the mainboard without a CPU. The result is a LED indicating a missing CPU and all fans spinning and operating normally.

Comment: I would suggest first looking at the stand offs and being sure you did not use too many. An extra stand off could allow for a short. I would suggest taking the board out. setting it on a table, 1 RAM, PSU, no HARD drives, and use a regular CPU cooler. See if it powers up. You could have a PSU and MOBO problem...Just because they are new, does not mean they are in working order. Had an ASUS MOBO that was bad twice.

Comment: I'm a PC-Technician. Don't worry. I don't make beginner's mistakes like that.

I've tested just about anything. Only thing I left out is breadboarding the entire thing.

Well I have tested both my old and my new PSU. Same issue.
So it can't be the PSU (alone). And the PSU in this computer has been working for at least 2 weeks before this issue arose.

Comment: Now I've done even breadboarding.
I can't figure out the cause of this issue for the life of me.
Only thing that would make sense at this point, is a busted CPU making the PC unable to do the checks and calculations for even POSTing.

Comment: Have you checked carefully for any signs that water has leaked out of the cooling system? There might be only a small amount of residue left where it has dried out, but that could be enough to prevent it working. Also, have you tried a different mains socket and lead? I think you *might* be able to boot that M/B with no processor installed (for the purpose of updating the BIOS).

Comment: I've actually had a leak once, but that was still destilled water. No additives, no coloring. And that was half a year ago.
"A different mains socket and lead"? I don't quite follow. You mean outside of the case? I have not, but I assure you all sockets work as intended and I'm running my TV off the same socket anyway.
Hmm.. I suppose I can try.